# Programmatically show controls in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a MPMoviePlayerController subclass that should show the controls when playback is finished. I have attached a responder to the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification  and tried setting the control style as follows:

```
[self setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
```

This is not working. In essence, at the end of the video I want to controls to show. 
How can I show controls programatically?

NOTE: The controller is NOT in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Are you sure that MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is getting notified? You can set a breakpoint or an NSLog message there to make sure.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this Robert?

Comment: I'm afraid it's too long ago to remember, but I think in the end we changed to using a different player?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find my full Code about this , it's working with me

add .h class add this

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController * moviePlayer;
```

at .m class add this code "pass the movie URl"

```
-(void) playMovie:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSURL *theOutputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    if(_moviePlayer)
        [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer setContentURL:theOutputURL];
    else
        _moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theOutputURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayer.moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:_moviePlayer.moviePlayer];

    if (![_moviePlayer.moviePlayer isPreparedToPlay])
        [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    _moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
    _moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer setContentURL:theOutputURL];
    _moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height);
    [_moviePlayer shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
}


- (void) moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange: (NSNotification *) notification {
    if (_moviePlayer.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) {
        [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer setContentURL:[_moviePlayer.moviePlayer contentURL]];
        [_moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
    }
}

-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    //  to add your code after playback is finished

}
```